# How can I build "user group" access control into WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

WordPress has some lovely features for storing revisions, editor approval of content, etc.

I'd like to expand on them by creating the concept of a **user group/organisation**.

I want:

- to be able to attach posts to an organisation
- to be able to attach users to an organisation (and ideally make it so that users can invite other users to their same org)
- users can only make changes to posts in the same org as them, everything else is read only.

I can do the first two with a custom post type and an Advanced Custom Fields [post object field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/), but I'm stumbling on the last one and would appreciate some pointers.

I imagine I would need to create a custom role with `add_role()`, but I'm not sure what capabilities it should have.

I imagine I'll need to override a hook *somewhere* to check if the thing the user is trying to edit is in their org.

Only relevant code so far is:

```
register_post_type("organisation");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, on WordPress, the default user system is: admin can do everything, editors can edit every post, authors can only edit their posts.

There are some plugins like https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ that may be useful for your needs. Have a look at that!